# Send email to mailgun with attachment from classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, mailgun

I am trying to get an old application from classic asp to send emails through mailgun api.  I can get it to where it will send a regular email with no attachments but I can not get it to work when I am trying to send as multipart/form-data.  It errors out with no detailed error response.

Here is my latest attempt of the function to send the email.

```
Function SendMailSync(toAddress, fromAddress, subject, body, htmlBody, attachment)
    Dim httpPostData
    Dim mailGunMessageUrl
    Const MAILGUN_BASE_URL = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/www.domain.com"
    Const MAILGUN_API_KEY = "myapikey"
    httpPostData = "from=" & fromAddress
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&to=" & toAddress
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&subject=" & subject
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&text=" & body
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&html=" & htmlBody
    if attachment <> "" then
        httpPostData = httpPostData & "&attachment=" & attachment
    end if
    sBoundary = String(6, "-") & Replace(Mid(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36), "-", "")
    set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    mailGunMessageUrl = MAILGUN_BASE_URL & "/messages"
    http.Open "POST", mailGunMessageUrl, false, "api", MAILGUN_API_KEY
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & sBoundary
    http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic AUTH_STRING"
    http.Send httpPostdata
    If http.status <> 200 Then
        Response.Write "An error occurred: " & http.responseText
    End If
    SendMailSync = http.responseText
    Set http = Nothing
End Function
```

Here is the function where it will send a basic email with no attachment.

```
Function SendMailSync(toAddress, fromAddress, subject, body, htmlBody)
    Dim httpPostData
    Dim mailGunMessageUrl
    Const MAILGUN_BASE_URL = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/www.domain.com"
    Const MAILGUN_API_KEY = "myapikey"
    httpPostData = "from=" & fromAddress
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&to=" & toAddress
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&subject=" & subject
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&text=" & body
    httpPostData = httpPostData & "&html=" & htmlBody
    set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    mailGunMessageUrl = MAILGUN_BASE_URL & "/messages"
    http.Open "POST", mailGunMessageUrl, false, "api", MAILGUN_API_KEY
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic AUTH_STRING"
    http.Send httpPostdata
    If http.status <> 200 Then
        Response.Write "An error occurred: " & http.responseText
    End If
    SendMailSync = http.responseText
    Set http = Nothing
End Function
```

Does anyone see what else I need to tweak in order to get the multipart/form-data to send.

Comment: According to [documentation][1], API needs a path of the attached file and no boundary key


  [1]: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples